# STM32 TIM1 Input Interrupt Setting

Tags: stm32, timer, stm32cubeide

I would like to get help with the input interrupt setting at TIM1. The inputs are PWM with different frequency. What I need is to get the rising edges and calculate the frequency of the input signals. I know that at other TIMs, I can just enable the global interrupt. However, for the TIM1, what should I choose for the interrupt? I believe the "Clock Source" has to be set as well, correct?

[image]